# SAS do loop and deleting unwanted records

Tags: arrays, sas

I have the sample code as following:

```
ID  DX  S_DT
1   VV  12/20/2013
1   VV  12/21/2013
2   VV  3/11/2006
2   VV  6/20/2008
2   VV  6/4/2009
2   VV  6/5/2009
3   VV  11/12/2001
3   VV  11/13/2001
3   VV  1/1/2014
```

I want my final data to look like this, except with the bolded dates set as zero:

```
ID  d_dt1        d_dt2           d_dt3          d_dt4
1   12/20/2013  **12/21/2013**      
2   3/11/2006   6/20/2008       **6/4/2009**    **6/5/2009**
3   11/12/2001  **11/13/2001**  1/1/2014
```

Here is my code:

```
data data_out;
SET data_in;

by ID S_dt;

retain d num_d prev_d_dt d_dt1-d_dt4;

array d_dt(4) d_dt1-d_dt4;

array dur(3) dur1-dur3;
if first.ID then do;

d=0;
num_d=0;
prev_d_dt=.;
do i = 1 to 4;
d_dt(i)=.;
end;
end;
if (DX='VV' and prev_d_dt ne S_dt ) then do; 
d=1;
num_d+1;
prev_d_dt=S_dt;
d_dt(num_D)=S_dt;
end;
end;
end;
if (last.ID) then do;
current_ddt=.;
do  i = 1 to 3;
dur(i)=d_dt(i+1) - d_dt(i);
if ( dur(i) >= 270) then do;
current_ddt=d_dt(i+1);
dur(i) = d_dt(i+1) - d_dt(i);
end;
if (dur(i) < 270) then do;
d_dt(i+1)=.;
current_ddt=d_dt(i+2);
dur(i+1)=d_dt(i+2) - d_dt(i);
end;
end;
output;
end;
keep patid num_d d_dt1-d_dt4 dur1-dur3 current_ddt;
format d_dt1-d_dt4 current_ddt mmddyy10.;
run;
```

I am having trouble setting those unwanted dates to zero.

Comment: What do you mean by *set to zero*?  If you set a date variable to zero then that means the date `01JAN1960`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Hi Tom, what I meant by "setting to zero" is to set it to missing so that in my future analysis I won't see this "unwanted" date.

Comment: I guess I should have said set to "missing".  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

one way to do is to transpose and then use arrays for calculations.

```
data  have;
input ID  DX $  S_DT:mmddyy10.;
format s_dt mmddyy10.;
datalines;
1   VV  12/20/2013
1   VV  12/21/2013
2   VV  3/11/2006
2   VV  6/20/2008
2   VV  6/4/2009
2   VV  6/5/2009
3   VV  11/12/2001
3   VV  11/13/2001
3   VV  1/1/2014
;

/* sorting the data*/

proc sort data = have;
by id s_dt;
run;

/* transposing the data*/

proc transpose data =have out =have1 (drop =_name_) prefix =date;
by id ;
 var s_dt;
run;

 /* picking all the date variables and counting number of variables
  for array processing in next step*/

  proc sql;
  select name , count(name)-1 into :date SEPARATED by ' ',
  :cnt
 from dictionary.columns
 where memname = 'HAVE1'
 and upcase(name) like 'DATE%';

  %put &date &cnt;
 /* data processing*/

data have2;
set have1;
array date(*) &date;
dateno =date1;
format dateno mmddyy10.;
do i = 1 to &cnt;
if date(i) -date(i+1) = -1 then do ;
call missing(date(i));
call missing (date(i+1));
end;
end;
drop date1 i;
run;

 /* putting variables in the order*/

 data have_final;
 retain id &date;
  set have2(rename =dateno=date1);
 run;
```

Comment: thanks Kiran.  The only thing is that these are mocked-up data.  My real data consists of approx. 250K patients with about 100 of those d_dts.  Would you still recommend me to transpose or I should process using ARRAY and RETAIN statement to get to one-row-per-patient?  Thanks!

Comment: I would not recommend transpose, unless you want in wide form. check this link out https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2015/06/19/can-you-lag-and-lead-at-the-same-time-if-using-the-sas-data-step-yes-you-can/

Comment: Great link thanks!  Would you have any input in terms of how to write a nested do-loop to get rid of those unwanted dates (indicated by surrounding **).  Consider those dates being delivery dates of babies.  It would only be a valid delivery date if the second one is at least 270 days after the first one.  In my "last.patid" statement, how do I set those unwanted ones to zero (so that I don't include them in my next steps) and keep the ones I want?

Comment: One thing worth mentioning, I keep running into problems like this:  assuming dur(1) = d_dt2 - d_dt1 and dur(1) is < 270.  Then I would set d_dt2 to be zero.  However when the do loop goes on, my dur(2) will become a missing date subtracting d_dt(1), so it should have been d_dt3 - d_dt1.

Comment: sorry, I am not clear what you are asking. do you want to add one more condition